# What's the probability of winning 10 lotteries with the same number?

Tags: probability, lotteries

Assuming I play a Lottery where I can buy a slip with exactly one random number from $1$ to $10$. The Probability of winning this lottery is $\frac{1}{10}$, as only $1$ winning number will be drawn.

Now I add a second lottery game on this Lottery Slip (again $1$ random number from $1$ to $10$). But, when I draw a winning number, this counts for both lotteries.

Example $1$: My Lottery Slip says "Game $1$: $5$ and Game $2$: $8. \implies$ Winning Number is $8\implies$ I won  2nd Lottery.

Example $2$: My Lottery Slip says Game $1$: $8$ and Game $2$: $8. \implies$ Winning Number is $8$ $\implies$ I won both Lotteries.

Example $3$: My Lottery Slip says Game $1$: $1$ and Game $2$: $8. \implies$ Winning Number is $7$ $\implies$ I lost both Lotteries.

What is the probability of at least winning once with a Lottery Slip of $10$ such games? Why?

Comment: Use mathjax please, and edit, I have done some part.

Comment: Sry, I am new to this forum. So I am not very familiar with mathjax. Tried my best now to edit.

Comment: Your question seems unclear , how do you define winning a game ? Winning both the draws ? @Max

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that, aren't winning numbers tied to the game? I mean, if you have two rounds of games, doesn't that mean that there would be two winning numbers?

Comment: Basically, isn't it one lottery and you buy 10 tickets (each with a random number)?

Comment: Sry if it is unclear. It is 10 Lotteries that (all together) win with the same number. Imagine the numbers for power ball are published, but at the same time those are valid for 9 other lotteries. In Germany, we have a Lottery Game Named "Super 6" and "Spiel 77". The winning number comes from "6 out of 49" Lottery. Simplified with 1 Number you play 3 Games. Simplified, if each lottery is the same and just one Number, what is my winning chance? We had a debate whether you had a 100% chance of winning if there were 10 such games combined. I assume it is ~65%  ( 1 - Not winning rate (0,9^10))

Answer (score 1):

Your answer of ~65 is almost correct.

However, you have ten of these "double lottery" games. That means the not winning rate is $0.9\cdot 0.9 = 0.81$, since you have two independent picks in one game. This occurs $10$ times, so $0.81^{10}\approx 0.1215$. Subtracting from $1$ gets the answer of $$1-0.1215 = 0.8785 = \boxed{87.9\%}.$$

Comment: Awsome Thanks :-)

Comment: @Max If this helped you, you can click the check mark next to my answer to accept it. Welcome to MSE :)